# Client Cannot See JS Animations

Tags: javascript, squarespace

I created simple slide up javascript animations on two elements on the homepage of my client's Squarespace site. You can see them here on the two text blocks below the homepage slider: https://www.ninedotdesign.co/

These animations I can see on my computer, 2 other computers in my office, and other computers external to my office. I'm in MA.

My client (lives in Arizona) says they cannot see them on their computer or 2 other computers in their region. They have confirmed they can see it on their cellphone which leads me to believe it's a DNS issue.

Any idea why they might not be seeing this animation?

Comment: Seems likely its not a code issue, so SO may not be the best place to get an answer. I wouldn't really know which other stack exchange site might be good alternatives. Perhaps the issue will self correct as the relevant systems update. Also they could try clearing caches or using a different browser which would make a fresher more up to date request. Sorry if these are obvious hope it helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS Animation Not Visible on Client's Computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54315039/js-animation-not-visible-on-clients-computer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a CDN issue with Squarespace. The endpoint that they are hitting hasn't propagated the changes that you've made to the website. Or it could be that they have cached data in their browser. Maybe ask them to try on another browser on their computer or to flush their cache.

Comment: It turns out this was CDN related issue as this same issue has occurred now for both JS and CSS related styling. Squarespace delivers up the assets from the site and occasionally fails to load specific assets causing the site to have missing functionality or styling.

Answer (score 0):

In your ref attribute at the end of each `.js` file append a question mark with any random digit or alphabet to resolve this issue for example:
`src='...320/scripts/site-bundle.js?324'` This forces the browser to re cache